# How do I send a HttpStatusCode.Continue and keep listening for a body?

Tags: c#, httplistener

It doesn't send it by just setting the property, it apparently only sends after calling Response.Close(). 
But then the stream stays closed and the client can't send the body anymore.
How do I send a HttpStatusCode.Continue response while still being able to read the request body and write a new response?

```
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Continue;
                context.Response.KeepAlive = true;
                context.Response.Close();
                // cannot access disposed object!!
                using (var body = context.Request.InputStream) {}
```

Comment: I believe that the system should do this for you [automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879120/supporting-the-expect-100-continue-header-with-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: doesnt seem to be true, I'm getting the request with no body and Expect: 100-continue header. So I have to respond to that myself, no? Otherwise it doesnt work